# Http JSON POST request returns empty body response with ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, fiware-orion

I am playing with ruby & services, I try to retreive a json response, BUT only get an empty body response :

```
uri = URI("http://.../v1/queryContext")
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path, initheader = {'content-type' => 'application/json', 'Accept' => 'application/json'})
req.body = {
           "entities": [
           {
               "type": "Printer",
               "isPattern": "false",
               "id": "UM1"
           }
       ]
       }.to_json
       response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port) do |http|
         http.request(req)
       end
```

Requests works fine **(Status 200 / Message OK)** but the JSON content that returns is not there (**response.body.size** = 0). very strange as I can see that its produced by the server.

```
Response payload: '{
  "contextResponses" : [
    {
      "contextElement" : {
        "type" : "Printer",
        "isPattern" : "false",
        "id" : "UM1",
        "attributes" : [
          {
            "name" : "bed",
            "type" : "float",
            "value" : "50"
          },
          {
            "name" : "temperature",
            "type" : "float",
            "value" : "180"
          }
        ]
      },
      "statusCode" : {
        "code" : "200",
        "reasonPhrase" : "OK"
      }
    }
  ]
}
'
```

Also, The following curl equivalent Works fine :

```
(curl http://.../v1/queryContext -s -S --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --header 'Accept: application/json' -d @- | python -mjson.tool) <<EOF
{
    "entities": [
        {
            "type": "Printer",
            "isPattern": "false",
            "id": "UM1"
        }
    ]
} 
EOF
```

I have the same exact issue using gems like httpclient or unirest. Is There anything special in Ruby that has to be done to receive the awaited json contents ?

Thanks

Comment: OK Got It. it was related to the scope of the response that ran in a function, even if the other values were fine (response.status & response.message), response.body was lost out of the function.

Answer (score 4):

Your code looks fine, I would suggest clearing bundle's cache (`bundle clean --force`) and install packages again.

Have you also tried running it on a different machine?

By the way, here's a clear example about doing a json request with the HTTP library you are using:
https://www.socialtext.net/open/very_simple_rest_in_ruby_part_3_post_to_create_a_new_workspace

Comment: Thanks, Yes I tried on another machine and I get the same result. I also tried a localhost connection from the server.

Answer (score 0):

It seems body of your request pretty print formatted. If you use object mapper or et. could you please check your object mapper have enabled prettyprint property or something like that? If it is enabled, remove it and try again. If you don't use object mapper, try to send a compact body instead of formatted one.

Good luck!